HttpContext.Current.Request.Params is null when throttling on slow network speed
I am making a request to a .net framework 4.8 controller route, and for some reason on Chrome browser when throttling the network speed to slow, HttpContext.Current.Request.Params, HttpContext.Current will be null. When I turn throttling off, the params will be there populated.
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("post-data")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
        {
            // HttpContext.Current.Server is null here
            string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/root");
            try
            {
                // HttpContext.Current.Request.Params is null here
                var response = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.Get("someValue");

                if (!validated)
                {
                     // Error handling
                }
                else
                {
                   // Process rest of form data in HttpContext.Current.Request.Params

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
            }

            return someThing;
        }


How are you sending the request? Are you using a basic HTML form that is posted, or some sort of client-side script?

I am using React with npm axios.post

@JohnWu after looking more, it looks like with the debugger on, in the httpContext.current object, there are many properties that show an error Cannot evaluate expression because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.
What does this mean. The output window also shows The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (13652) has exited with code 0 (0x0)

I suggest you capture the traffic (e.g. using Fiddler, or by examining W3C logs ) and see if the stuff you're looking for is there. That will tell you if the problem is the client or the server.

@JohnWu im not sure if its client side because in chrome I can see the payload that was sent with the request has all the data in it. Once it hits server, everything is null. This again only happens when I throttle the network speed to slow on Chrome browser. Im trying to mimic an issue where on prod, the same thing is happening.
